# iPhone 6S very slow after upgrading to iOS 11

Tags: iphone, ios

Recently I upgraded my iPhone 6S to iOS 11 from iOS 10. After upgrading many animations stutter a lot, sometimes screen transition animations are delayed by seconds. When I press and hold on the screen to get the cursor selection magnifying glass there is a delay of about 3 seconds until I see the magnified text.

Is there any way to improve this other than downgrading iOS?

I'm currently on iOS 11.0.2.

See below for jankiness when pressing back button. There's a few seconds delay for the title to appear. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zx5lo22wj4hhbjf/42CDDAD7-103E-4555-8E2D-511D655F2F70.mov?dl=0

Comment: This might potentially be caused by the file system conversion using lots of system resources. Can you wait a little while to see if it gets better? Do you have a very large SSD?

Comment: It's been a few days since I upgraded and still about the same slowness. I have 49.5 / 64 GB used. Should it take more than a few days?

Comment: Same here, been stuttering for days.

Comment: So now after a couple weeks it's definitely gotten much better. Still feels slower than iOS 10 but it's at least somewhat bearable now. Going to get a new iPhone soon anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The next best thing is to restore the iPhone software. Meaning erase the software and then using iTunes on a computer to restore the software with a refreshed iOS 11.0.2.

1. Backup iPhone via iCloud (optional but highly recommended)
2. Plug in iPhone to iTunes and click restore iPhone. iTunes should also automatically backup the iPhone also. - https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201252
   **Make sure iTunes is up to date and then restore.
3. Once restore is done you are going to get the hello screen on the iPhone. Set up the iPhone properly then when you get the Apps & Data screen, **restore from iCloud backup** (unless you chose not to back it up). - https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT204184
4. Then your phone should be back up and working with your stuff back on it and the software cleaned up.

Let me know if you have any concerns/questions/issues.