# Reinstall iOS preserving apps and data

Tags: ios

Can I reinstall iOS (11) but preserve installed apps and data? I'm having some [issues with my phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/301038/20799) and I'd like to try reinstalling iOS but I'd rather not have to restore all of my apps and data as that would be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By doing an iCloud backup (not iTuens) you only preserve apps, data and most basic settings. Phone will look the same after you recover from an iCloud backup.

Doing the same but with local Itunes backup will preserve absolutely Everything.

To reinstall ios on the iPhone you can either connect it to Itunes and do the procedure from there or directly on phone by going:

Settings --> Generall --> Reset --> Erase all content and settings.

Unfortunately this is not documented anywhere so i can not reference it but from personal experience this is my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please follow these steps to retain all your data after restoring a fresh copy of iOS 11:

1. iOS: Go to Settings > iCloud and **turn off "Find My iPhone"**.
2. **Connect your iPhone** to a computer running iTunes 12.7 using a Lightning cable.
3. iOS: Enable Airplane mode and disable Wi-Fi and Bluetooth in Settings.
4. iTunes: Create an **encrypted backup of your iPhone** and verify that the process completed successfully.
5. iTunes: Select your iPhone and press "**Restore**...". This will download the current iOS 11 release and install a fresh copy on your iPhone.
6. iTunes: Once your iPhone is finished installing iOS 11 select "**Restore from backup**".